# .hgignore doesn't seem to be working

Tags: command-line, mercurial, tortoisehg, hgignore

I have a `.hgignore` file in my project's root directory and it's not doing squat.  When I do an `hg add`, every single file in my project directory is being added and tracked.  I get the same result whether I use tortoisehg or the command-line.  Command-line is my preference. What's going on here?

My `.hgignore` (taken from another question on SO):

```
# use glob syntax
syntax: glob

*.obj
*.pdb
*.user
*.aps
*.pch
*.vspscc
*.vssscc
*_i.c
*_p.c
*.ncb
*.suo
*.tlb
*.tlh
*.bak
*.cache
*.ilk
*.log
*.lib
*.sbr
*.scc
[Bb]in
[Dd]ebug*/
obj/
[Rr]elease*/
_ReSharper*/
[Tt]humbs.db
[Tt]est[Rr]esult*
[Bb]uild[Ll]og.*
*.[Pp]ublish.xml
*.resharper
```

Comment: Where is the `.hgignore` file in your project? Isn't it inside the `.hg` directory, right?

Comment: @brandizzi Per first line of my question it's in the project root directory.  It's sitting next to my .hg folder.

Comment: Your `.hgignore` content works for me. Whatever the problem is, I don't think it's your `.hgignore`. You might have to dig into the repo's `hgrc` and your global config.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I Just now fixed it and apparently it was some kind of issue with the file.  Going to post as an answer with more information.

Comment: @Pete you are right, my question was redundant. Sorry for the confusion, it is just that I make this mistake some times when started to use Mercurial :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently it was some issue with the encoding of the file.  I was editing the file in Notepad++ (tried ANSI and UTF-8 encodings) and the file looked fine when editing.  I had given up and decided to start over by using the command `notepad .hgignore`.  Then I pasted the contents from the file that was giving me trouble and everything was on a single line with no breaks.  I fixed the breaks, saved the file and it immediately worked.

I'm still not sure why the file looked fine in Notepad++ but was actually putting out garbage.

Comment: it might have been putting a BOM (byte order mark) at the front of the file, which is sometimes okay for UTF-16, but never okay for UTF-8 though editors on windows like to do it sometimes anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The `glob` match syntax takes the path into account.  You can switch to `syntax: relglob` for relative pathnames or prefix your patterns with `**/`.

Comment: hg st -i still returns nothing.  Also, the only tracked file I currently have is my .hgignore.

Comment: Try `hg --config "ui.ignore=.hgignore" stat -i` to ensure the hgignore location is not being overriden somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to tell mercurial where the global ignore file is located. I had to add this line under the `[ui]` section of my `.hgrc` for it to work.

```
ignore = ~/.hgignore
```